# orgo- ketone derivatives

Tags: reaction-mechanism

In the following reaction, I mix $\pu{0.25g}$ semicarbazide hydrochloride (M.M. $\pu{111.54 g/mol}$), $\pu{0.4g}$ sodium acetate ($\ce{CH3CO2Na}$), $\pu{3mL}$ of $\ce{H2O}$ (M.M of sodium acetate trihydrate is $\pu{136 g/mol}$), and $\pu{0.25 g}$ acetone (M.M $\pu{58.08 g/mol}$) in a large test tube.

My understanding of this reaction is that the sodium acetate deprotonates the semicarbazide hydrochloride to make it a good nuc while simultaneously buffering the aqueous solution to create ideal conditions for the acetone ketone to be protonated, become a good electrophile, and get attacked by the carbazide intermediate. I need help on how to figure out what the balanced equation is, how to find limiting reagants and how to determine what the theoretical yield of my product should be.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your description of the reaction so the balanced equation should be obvious to you: 1 eq Semicarbazide.HCl + 1 eq Sodium Acetate + 1 eq Acetone gives the carbazone of acetone (plus NaCl and AcOH).

The limiting reagent and yield is obtained by calculating how many moles of each reactant are present, which is the mass of reagent divided by the molecular weight. e.g. for Acetone it is 0.25/58.08 = 4.3 mmol

If you do this calculation for Sodium Acetate and Semicarbazide.HCl it will become clear which component is the limiting reagent.

The theoretical yield is the number of moles of limiting reagent x MW of the product acetone semicarbazone